# Uninstall one package from composer without updating everything else

Tags: package, composer-php, uninstallation

I have a project that uses Composer.  I want to remove a package (in my case Aspect Mock).

I remove the dependency from composer.json and delete all the vendor packages manually.  Then I run `php composer.phar install`.  It says

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
```

I do not want this warning, so I run `php composer.phar update` and it updates all my packages in composer.lock (which we have in SCM).

I do not want that either (I only want to remove one package) so instead of running `composer update`, I manually remove all references to the removable package in composer.lock.  Composer install still gives me this warning.

How can I delete a package installed by composer without updating everything else, and without introducing warnings into my workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating just the lock file: `composer update --lock`

Removing a package, deleting their files, updating the lock file all in one command without dealing with naked JSON data: `composer remove vendor/package` or `composer remove --dev vendor/package` - just the opposite of `require`.

Comment: This is outdated. The correct way is `composer update --lock`. See this [issue](https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/issues/92).

Answer (score 4):

`composer remove vendor/package` is the command you are looking for. It removes the package from composer.json as well as deleting it from the vendor folder.

You can read about its options at https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove

Comment: I know I've just answered an older question but I had the same problem as the OP and `composer update nothing` did not work for me.